# Google Chrome / Chromium event filter, local file hostname?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension to the Chrome and I'd like to filter WebNavigation.OnCompleted event so that it's only fired on certain domains.

I'm using it like this:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    // some code here...
}, {
      url : {hostEquals : 'www.foo.bar'}
   });
```

That works. Then I started testing this on a test page, which is located on my local computer. That's when I ran into the problem: what's the value of the filter when URL points to a file located on the local computer (i.e. what's the hostname of a local file from Chrome event filter perspective):

```
file:///home/usr/testfile.html
```

I know, the URL doesn't really contain a hostname, but I think it should be possible to filter these kind's of addresses too. I've tested different variations, like 'file:///', 'localhost' and '/' but none of them seem to get the job done. Leaving the filter empty equals no filtering at all.

The extension works fine without the filter, but I need to get this system to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a file URL that starts with "/home/user/", just use `urlPrefix`, e.g. as follows:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    // Some code here...
}, {
    url: [{
        hostEquals: 'example.com',
    }, {
        // Note: This filter will only match if
        // 1) You've declared the "file://*" or "<all_urls>" permission
        //    in manifest.json, and
        // 2) You've visited chrome://extensions and ticked the checkbox
        //    "Allow access to file URLs" at your extension.
        urlPrefix: 'file:///home/user/'
    }],
});
```

For other filters, see the documentation at [`chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted).

PS. The host name of a `file:`-URL is whatever that comes between the `file://` and the path. In case of `file:///`, it's an empty string.

Comment: Ok, I thought there would be all-in-one solution that works for every situation.